# javascript get average of inputs

Tags: javascript, average

I have a function which currently adds up the discounts received. I want to change the **sum** of the inputs to the **average** of each input.

```
function calculateAverageDiscount() {
    var avediscount = 0;
    $("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="discount"]').each(function () {
        avediscount += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#avediscount").text(avediscount.toFixed(2));
}
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your list of elements first:

```
var $disc = $("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="discount"]');
```

and then take its length:

```
var n = $disc.length;
```

and then take the sum, as you are, but using the previously obtained list so you *don't repeat yourself*.

```
$disc.each(function() {
    ...
});
```

the rest should be obvious... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the number of elements and then divide the total sum by that number.

```
var avediscount = 0;
var length = $("table.authors-list").find('input[name^="discount"]').each(function () {
    avediscount += +$(this).val();
}).length;
$("#avediscount").text(avediscount.toFixed(2)/length);
```